# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I obtain this error when I put a tablesorter plugin in my application. What kind of error is it? 
I load my plugin in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http:...."></script>
```

The code:

```
alert("HI");

         $("#tabella").tablesorter({sortList: [[3,1],[2,0]]});
            alert("BEFORE")
```

;
Anyone can help me?Anyone can explain me how how this error is generate?

Comment: You haven't loaded the library script

Comment: Have you added the reference to the plugin?

Comment: OR you are using it before the library is loaded

Comment: I edit my querstion,..I load plugin

Comment: Is [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323408/plugin-not-loading) similar to this one? Are you loading jQuery first? Or loading jQuery twice? Or maybe that code needs to be wrapped in a document ready event?